# Docusign api error in fetching documentbase64 through docusign node js sdk

Tags: docusignapi

I am getting below error while fetching documentbase64.

`The custom error module does not recognize this error`

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: Might want to follow this thread: https://github.com/docusign/docusign-esign-node-client/issues/295

Answer (score 1):

Please try again. This was a temporary issue on the DocuSign API side and should be now resolved.